# How to solve the system of 4 equations of four unknowns

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

Solve this system of the four equations of four unknowns $a, b, c, d>0 $

$$ 165(a+b+c)=abc\tag1   $$
$$220(a+b+d)=abd \tag2   $$
$$297(a+c+d)=acd\tag3   $$
$$540(b+c+d)=bcd \tag4   $$

I tried to solve it by following method. On substituting the values of two variables c & d  from equations (1) & (2) in the equations (3) & (4), I got

$$297a^3b^2-36300a^3-72600a^2b+78045ab^2-10781100a-21562200b=0\tag5 $$

$$540a^2b^3-36300b^3-72600ab^2+171600a^2b-39204000a-19602000b=0\tag6 $$

How to proceed? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: introducing P = a+b+c+d and Q = a b c d introduces 2 extra variables.Divisions among them may produce 6, but simpler looking equations to solve.

Answer (score 2):

When you have two ***non-linear*** equations in two unknowns,

$$F_1(x,y)=0$$

$$F_2(x,y)=0$$

you can use *resultants* to eliminate one unknown. There is no point in doing it by hand since nowadays, one can use computer algebra systems to do this efficiently. The command in *Mathematica* is,

$$\text{Resultant}[F_1(x,y),F_2(x,y),y]$$

where $y$ is the variable to be eliminated. Eliminating your $b$ using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5BResultant%5B297a%5E3b%5E2%20-%2036300a%5E3%20-%2072600a%5E2b%20%2B%2078045a%20b%5E2%20-%2010781100a%20-%2021562200b%2C540a%5E2b%5E3%20-%2036300b%5E3%20-%2072600a%20b%5E2%20%2B%20171600a%5E2b%20-%2039204000a%20-%2019602000b%2Cb%5D%5D), one finds,

$$a (-165 + a^2) (165 + a^2) (220 + a^2) (88944075 + 1281390 a^2 + 5962 a^4 + 9 a^6)=0$$